# How can I reset default theme on Jupyter Notebooks? (jt -r not working)

Tags: jupyter

I'm new to python and to jupyter notebooks, and I can't figure out how to reset my jupyter notebooks theme to the default.

I've opened my terminal, typed `jt -r`, cleared my browser cache, and restarted it, but I'm still stuck in the old theme. I've tried to remove the offending directories from the command line by using `rm -r` for /Users/mm/.jupyter/custom &/Users/mm/Library/Jupyter/nbextensions, and again cleared my cache without progress.

I know I'm flailing around a bit as a new user. I'm trying my best to reference other users' tips, but most just say "type jt -r and reset the browser cache", which hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually trying to change the font size of the dark theme and wrote the command:

`-jt -fs 200`

and it actually changed the theme back to the default one.
Before:
[Before changing font size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9HVN.jpg)

After:
[After changing font size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbIHL.jpg)